# Probablities random variables density

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

The probability that a radium atom doesn't disintegrate in $40$ seconds knowing that it didn't disintegrate in $12$ seconds is $0,4$. What is the probability of the atom not disintegrating in $70$ seconds if it didn't disintegrate in $12$ seconds?

I think I need to use density, but I don't know how I should use it. Is this an exponential distribution?

Comment: The presumption with simple radioactive decay (as opposed to a chain of decays) is that it is indeed exponential.  The simplest way to treat this problem is to simply recognize that because of the memoryless property of the exponential distribution, the first probability is simply the probability that the atom doesn't disintegrate in $40-12 = 28$ seconds.  Apply similar reasoning to the second probability (it sure is inconvenient that it wasn't $68$ seconds), and the problem should be straightforward.

Comment: Incidentally, I don't think this question falls under either probability-theory or discrete-mathematics, so I'm going to delete those tags.